# Is it possible to sort a TListBox using a custom sort comparator?

Tags: delphi

I need to sort my TListBox but I realized it is a lot of work to modify my code if I were to say make a TStringList, sort it and then copy those items into the Listbox. The main reason it's a lot of work is that I have many places in the code where the listbox contents are modified and I guess I would have to edit them all to force a sort at the time they are added, deleted or whatever.

I would much prefer something that let me just attach a method to a listbox somehow to sort it using my custom sort logic.

Is it somehow possible?

Comment: There is no way to attach a custom sort method. You can use `TStrings.CustomSort` to define your own sorting logic for the `TListBox.Items`, but it would still have to be called from your code each time you needed to re-sort the ListBox. Of couse, you could always write your own descendant of TListBox that added the event and called it from the appropriate locations.

Comment: Also note that `TListBox.Sorted` uses the Windows internal sort (by adding the `LBS_SORT` window style when the control is created), so you'll need to work around that also.

Comment: You can always create a function to do the work and call it when you need. How that is implemented then becomes irrelevant to the impact on the code base. Copy to TStringList and sort there is one option. There are others. I personally would sort in-place. But don't be afraid of writing methods/function to encapsulate functionality. You are allowed to do that.

Comment: List box can be virtual. Sort your stuff in a separate collection and feed the list box.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is no Problem! Look at this Code:

```
function CompareDates(List: TStringList; Index1, Index2: Integer): Integer;
var
  d1, d2: TDateTime;
begin
   d1 := StrToDate(List[Index1]);
   d2 := StrToDate(List[Index2]);
   if d1 < d2 then
     Result := -1
   else if d1 > d2 then 
     Result := 1
   else
     Result := 0;
end;

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  sl: TStringList;
begin
  sl := TStringList.Create; 
  try     
    sl.Assign(ListBox1.Items);
    sl.CustomSort(CompareDates);
    ListBox1.Items.Assign(sl);
  finally
    sl.Free
  end;
end;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Delphi XE or later, I have a possibility for you.

Note that I say "possibility" and not "solution" as it is more of a hack than anything else and I wouldn't really approve this in production code unless it was a last resort.

From what I understand, what you are essentially trying to achieve is override the behavior of the Add function (which is virtual) to make it insert at the right position based on a custom order. (If you need to also override insert, this works too). If it was possible to override the TStrings descendant TListbox uses, that would be simple, but we are not that lucky.

Delphi XE introduced a new class called TVirtualMethodInterceptor (Rtti unit) that allows to intercept virtual method to do whatever we want to do with it. We can inspect and modify the parameters, call other functions, or litterally cancel the call and do nothing at all.

Here's how the proof of concept I made looked like:

```
//type
//  TCompareFunc<T1> = reference to function (const Arg1, Arg2 : T1) : Integer;
procedure TForm4.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
var vCompareFunc : TCompareFunc<string>;
    RttiContext : TRttiContext;
    vAddMethod  : TRttiMethod;
    vRttiType : TRttiType;
begin
  RttiContext := TRttiContext.Create;
  vRttiType := RttiContext.GetType(TStrings);
  vAddMethod := vRttiType.GetMethod('Add');

  vCompareFunc :=  MyCompareFunc;
  Fvmi := TVirtualMethodInterceptor.Create(Listbox1.Items.ClassType);

  Fvmi.OnBefore :=   procedure(Instance: TObject; Method: TRttiMethod;
                        const Args: TArray<TValue>; out DoInvoke: Boolean; out Result: TValue)
                      var
                        idx : Integer;
                      begin
                        if Method = vAddMethod then
                        begin //if it's the Add method, map it to Insert at the right position
                          DoInvoke := False;
                          BinarySearch(TStrings(Instance), Args[0].AsString, vCompareFunc,idx);
                          TStrings(Instance).Insert(idx, Args[0].AsString);
                        end;
                      end;


  Fvmi.Proxify(Listbox1.Items);

end;
```

This proof of concept intercept the call to TStrings.add and map it to binarysearch/Insert so that the items of the list are always in the right order. This does not override the Insert or Assign function, or any other function modifying the list. If you want to use this approach, you need to override all the "offending" functions.

Disclaimer : Since I have never really used this technique, don't consider this example as the golden rule for TVirtualMethodInterceptor's usage. It does work, but it might have performance implications or others that I'm unaware of.

One important point to mention (from Barry Kelly's blog, see below)

> One thing the TVirtualMethodInterceptor class doesn't have, however,
>   is a way to unhook (unproxify) the object. If the object is never
>   unhooked, it's important that the object doesn't outlive the
>   interceptor, because the interceptor needs to allocate executable
>   memory in order to create the little stubs with which it redirects
>   method calls to the events.

If you want to dig deeper, here's a pretty good article on the subject:
http://blog.barrkel.com/2010/09/virtual-method-interception.html

Comment: This isn't practical is it?

Comment: An [`Unproxify()`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE7/en/System.Rtti.TVirtualMethodInterceptor.Unproxify) method was added to `TVirtualMethodInterceptor` in XE2.