# How to custom sort a VCL TListBox?

Tags: c++, c++builder, vcl

I'm trying to figure out how to supply my own custom sort method to items and strings in a `TListBox`.

My list box stores a custom object in its `Object` property, and I need to use that in the custom sort.

I'm basing the below code on this post (Delphi): [Is it possible to sort a TListBox using a custom sort comparator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27382906/is-it-possible-to-sort-a-tlistbox-using-a-custom-sort-comparator)

My custom sort function looks like this

```
int __fastcall SortListByValue (TStringList* sl, int item1, int item2)
{
    IniKey* k1 = (IniKey*) sl->Objects[item1];
    IniKey* k2 = (IniKey*) sl->Objects[item2];
    return k1->mValue < k2->mValue;
}
```

The key values are strings. Currently they can be "-", "Yes", "No" and "Pass".

And the code where it is called is like this:

```
void __fastcall TMainForm::sortByValueAExecute(TObject *Sender)
{
    Log(lInfo) << "Sorting list based on Values";
    TStringList* sl = new TStringList();
    sl->Assign(imagesLB->Items);
    sl->CustomSort(SortListByValue);
    imagesLB->Items->Assign(sl);
}
```

The above code does "something" to the list, but its not sorted.

The resulting list starts with "-" items, and all "Yes" items are consecutive. "No" and "Pass" and "-" items are then scrambled.

Any clues?

Comment: I believe I was looking at old code for TStringList. I'll update with new code in a second

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your sort function is expected to return a value that is `< 0`, `0`, or `> 0`, depending on the desired order of the two input parameters.  But you are not doing that correctly.  You are returning either `0` or `1`, but never `< 0`, because you are returning the (implicitly converted) result of a boolean expression, which can only be `false` or `true`.

You need to change this line:

```
return k1->mValue < k2->mValue;
```

To this instead:

```
if (k1->mValue < k2->mValue) return -1;
else if (k1->mValue > k2->mValue) return 1;
else return 0;
```

Alternatively, use the RTL's [`AnsiCompareStr()`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.SysUtils.AnsiCompareStr) or [`CompareStr()`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.SysUtils.CompareStr) function instead:

```
return AnsiCompareStr(k1->mValue, k2->mValue);
```

```
return CompareStr(k1->mValue, k2->mValue);
```